# How to recover Flink job (Kubernetes) from savepoint?

Tags: kubernetes, apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-checkpoint

I'm running Flink 1.14 app (jar embded in docker image) over Kubernetes cluster. Configs like `parallelism`, `numberOfTaskSlots` and etc. are specified in `ConfigMap` as `flink-conf.yaml`.
Checkpoint directory (hdfs) is hardcoded in jar (`setCheckpointStorage("hdfs://...")`). Savepoint location is not specified anywhere.

Everything works fine, checkpoints are created, in case of errors the application is automatically restored from these checkpoints.

**Question** — how to trigger the savepoint operation manually, then manually reload the application from this savepoint?

Please take into account, that I'm on Kubernetes cluster in Flink application mode (each Flink app is independent k8s deployment) and I'm aware of `-s hdfs://...` parameter, but not sure how to apply that parameter in my case.

Answer (score 0):

From the [official docs](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-kubernetes-operator-docs-main/docs/custom-resource/job-management/#manual-savepoint-triggering):

> Users can trigger savepoints manually by
> defining a new (different/random) value to the variable
> savepointTriggerNonce in the job specification:
>
> job:
> ...
> savepointTriggerNonce: 123

So what I would try to run `kubectl edit job` on the Flink job, update the `savepointTriggerNonce` value to a new random value, and then restart the job. It should start from the last savepoint.

Comment: And how to restart the job in that case?

Comment: Editing the deployment is a manual step, so restarting would be the same. You need to do that restart automatically?